# Remove Item from jQuery autocomplete using Tokenfield

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to remove an item from a jQuery autocomplete dropdown once it has been selected. I'm useing this library (for tokenization) https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield and jQuery autocomplete.

Here's my HTML:

`<input class='form-control' id='tokenfield' type='text'>`

And my js:

```
DROPDOWN = ['one', two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  $("#tokenfield").tokenfield({
    autocomplete: {
      source: DROPDOWN,
      delay: 100
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
  }); 


$("#tokenfield").on("tokenfield:createtoken", function(event) {
    selectedToken = event.attrs.value;
    // remove selectedToken from the autocomplete source
  });
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield) (see the end of the [methods section](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#methods)):

> You can also set new options for the autocomplete or typehead objects from the original input above like so: `$('#tokenfield').data('bs.tokenfield').$input.autocomplete({source: new_array})`

So, assuming your callback is set up sanely and that I'm using the right method to retrieve the existing tokens, it would be something like this:

```
$("#tokenfield").on("tokenfield:createtoken", function(event) {
    var selectedToken = event.attrs.value;
    var existingTokens = $('#tokenfield').tokenfield('getTokens', false);

    // Removing item from array is left as exercise to reader
    var newTokens = removeFromArray(existingTokens, selectedToken);

    // Per docs
    $('#tokenfield').data('bs.tokenfield').$input.autocomplete(
        {source: newTokens});
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is right.  getTokens retrieves the selected values, not values from autocomplete.

Comment: @michaelAdam: you may be right. From [docs](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#methods): **.tokenfield('getTokens', active)** *Get an array of tokens from the input. Set active to true to return only selected tokens.* Updated answer to add second parameter to `getTokens` call set to `false`.